# Unclear behavior of instantiation coupled with a method

Tags: python

I used to maintain compilers for a living, but this one befuddles me.

It seems if you create a class and give it a method, you ought to be able to instantiate an instance and do a trivial method at the same time.  Here are two ways that look like they should do the same thing but don't:

```
class foo(object) :

    def __init__(self, val) :
        self.val = val

    def set_new(self, new) :
        self.val = new


a = foo(2).set_new(3)

print a

>>> None

a = foo(2)
s.set_new(3)

>>> ..instance at ox7fe2...
```

Were I designing it, the call `a = foo(2).set_new(3)` would have as it's primary action to create the object and use the constructor; the `.set_new()` is a subsidiary task.

It looks like it all is OK if the method returns 'self', but that then means that the method can't return a useful result of its own when it is called standalone (like a success code or some such).

Perhaps some way of knowing, inside `set_new()`, that it is a 'nested' or 'chained' call - though that still makes the return value inconsistent from call to call.

Comment: What should the return value be that is assigned to `a`…? Either you interpret it as `a = ( foo(2).set_new(3) )` or as `( a = foo(2) ).set_new(3)`. It seems you expect the latter, but I know of no language that interprets chained methods that way.

Comment: One of the reasons I dislike the '.' method of calling methods in OO languages.

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly simple. In the first call 2 things are happening. `foo(2)` will create the instance and then `.set_new(3)` will set the value to 3. Since here the output of the last action is assigned to `a`, the problem is that the `.set_new()` return nothing (`None` value), so `a` will be `None`. Just return `self` in `set_new()` and then the chained call will work just fine.